# TextInputLayout setCounterEnables doesn't work - Android

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have a layout with a `TextInputLayout`s elements and I want to enable counter of characters. The problem is it's not working and I can't see the counter when I run the app.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/create_step_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/create_step_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/create_step_padding">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Shipper Text Area-->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/shipper_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_area_background"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/text_input_layout_side_padding"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/text_input_layout_side_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/text_input_layout_top_padding"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintTextStyle"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/shipper_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:hint="@string/shipper_field"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="5"
                android:overScrollMode="always"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <!-- Consignee Text Area-->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/consignee_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_area_background"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_input_layout_side_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/text_input_layout_top_padding"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintTextStyle"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shipper_layout">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/consignee_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:hint="@string/consignee_field"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="5"
                android:overScrollMode="always"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Airport of Departure -->

        <!-- Airport of Destination -->

        <com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.AirportAutoCompleteEditText
            android:id="@+id/aodep_field"
            android:layout_width="217dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.512"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <com.silverfix.dgdeditor.utils.views.AirportAutoCompleteEditText
            android:id="@+id/aodes_field"
            android:layout_width="217dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/aodep_field" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/aodep_field"
            android:textAppearance="@style/DefaultTextStyle"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/consignee_layout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/aodes_field"
            android:textAppearance="@style/DefaultTextStyle"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As you can see, I enabled `app:counterEnabled` in the `TextInputLayout`s.
Then I try to set the max chars inside my code.

Here is the code:

```
shipperTextArea = (TextInputLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shipper_layout);
consigneeTextArea = (TextInputLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.consignee_layout);

shipperTextArea.setCounterMaxLength(60);
consigneeTextArea.setCounterMaxLength(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the counter in xml files, add this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    app:counterMaxLength="60"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
```

i think that don't need to set in the java class.